# Remove every nth item from array

Tags: php, arrays, array-unset

I want to unset every second item from an array. I don't care about if the keys are reordered or not.

Of course I want it fast and elegant. Is it maybe possible without a loop and temporary variables?

Answer (score 1):

My own solution so far:

```
for ( $i = 1; isset($arr[$i]); $i += 2) { 
    unset($arr[$i]);
}
```

The pro is, that it needs no if-statement, the con that a variable (`$i`) is still needed and it works only if the keys are numeric and without gaps.

Comment: I guess this is the only way. But a correction would be
    for($i = 2; $i < len($arr); $i + = 2){ isset($arr[$i]?unset($arr[$i]))}

Because lets assume the 4th cell is unset already. The loop will exit then and there it wont go to the length

Comment: @AbhilashCherukat Thanks, I changed the description.

Answer (score 0):

If you have an array like

```
Array
(
    [0] => test1
    [1] => test2
    [2] => test3
    [3] => test4
    [4] => test5
)
```

Then you can go with below code. It will remove every second item of array.

```
$i = 1;
foreach ($demo_array as $key => $row) {
    if($i%2 == '0')
    {
        unset($demo_array[$key]);
    }
    $i++;
}
```

Hope this will helps you. Let mee know if you need any further help on it.

Comment: The pro is, this version works with all kinds of keys. However I don't understand why the 0 is a string?

Comment: Yes this will work with all kind of keys. Also we can directly use it as 0 but it's good habit to compare value with double quote.

Comment: @PHPWeblineindia Why in the world would it be a good habit to compare a variable which can only be a number against a string?

Answer (score 0):

```
 function arr_unset_sec(&$arr, $key)
 {
   if($key%2 == 0)
   {
     unset($arr[$key]);  
   }
 }
 array_walk($arr, 'arr_unset_sec');
```

Assuming $arr may be some array. Check this piece of code.

Answer (score 0):

Another solution without a loop:

```
$arr = array('a', 'b', 'c', 'd', 'e');
$arr = array_filter( $arr, function($k) { return $k % 3 === 0; }, ARRAY_FILTER_USE_KEY);
```

Pro, it needs no loop. Cons, it is a lot slower than my other version (with a for loop), looks a bit scary and depends again on the keys.

Comment: @mickmackusa you are right. I changed it to also support every 3rd or whichever.

Answer (score 0):

I'll provide two methods (`array_filter()` and a `foreach()` loop) which will leverage the condition `$i++%$n` to target the elements to be removed.

**Both methods will work on indexed and associative arrays.**

1. `$i++` This is post-incrementation.  Effectively, the value will be evaluated first, then incremented second.
2. `%`  This is the modulo operator - it returns the "remainder" from the division of the leftside value from the rightside value.
3. The return value from the condition will either be `0` or a positive integer.  For this reason, php's inherent "type juggling" feature can be used to convert `0` to `false` and positive integers as `true`.
4. In the `array_filter()` method, the `use()` syntax must use `&$i` so that the variable is "modifiable".  Without the `&`, `$i` will remain static (unaffected by post-incrementation).
5. In the `foreach()` method, The condition is inverted `!()` in comparison to the `array_filter()` method.  `array_filter()` wants to know what to "keep"; `foreach()` wants to know what to `unset()`.

Code: ([Demo](http://sandbox.onlinephpfunctions.com/code/2c2dba61ff25ef9838ebb7b4f9373d5ed2d6a56f))

```
//                          if:$n=2        $n=3        $n=4        $n=5
$array=['first'=>1,
        2,                  // remove
        'third'=>3,         //             remove
        'fourth'=>4,        // remove                  remove
        5,                  //                                     remove
        6,                  // remove      remove
        'seventh'=>7,
        'eighth'=>8,        // remove                  remove
        'ninth'=>9];        //             remove

// if $n is 0 then don't call anything, because you aren't attempting to remove anything
// if $n is 1 then you are attempting to remove every element, just re-declare as $array=[]

for($n=2; $n<5; ++$n){
    $i=1;  // set counter
    echo "Results when filtering every $n elements: ";
    var_export(array_filter($array,function()use($n,&$i){return $i++%$n;}));
    echo "\n---\n";
}

echo "\n\n";
// Using a foreach loop will be technically faster (only by a small margin) but less intuitive compared to
// the literal/immediate interpretation of "array_filter".

for($n=2; $n<5; ++$n){
    $i=1;
    $copy=$array;
    foreach($copy as $k=>$v){
        if(!($i++%$n)) unset($copy[$k]);  // or $i++%$n==0 or $i++%$n<1
    }
    echo "Results when unsetting every $n elements: ";
    var_export($copy);
    echo "\n---\n";
}
```

Output:

```
Results when filtering every 2 elements: array (
  'first' => 1,
  'third' => 3,
  1 => 5,
  'seventh' => 7,
  'ninth' => 9,
)
---
Results when filtering every 3 elements: array (
  'first' => 1,
  0 => 2,
  'fourth' => 4,
  1 => 5,
  'seventh' => 7,
  'eighth' => 8,
)
---
Results when filtering every 4 elements: array (
  'first' => 1,
  0 => 2,
  'third' => 3,
  1 => 5,
  2 => 6,
  'seventh' => 7,
  'ninth' => 9,
)
---


Results when unsetting every 2 elements: array (
  'first' => 1,
  'third' => 3,
  1 => 5,
  'seventh' => 7,
  'ninth' => 9,
)
---
Results when unsetting every 3 elements: array (
  'first' => 1,
  0 => 2,
  'fourth' => 4,
  1 => 5,
  'seventh' => 7,
  'eighth' => 8,
)
---
Results when unsetting every 4 elements: array (
  'first' => 1,
  0 => 2,
  'third' => 3,
  1 => 5,
  2 => 6,
  'seventh' => 7,
  'ninth' => 9,
)
---
```

Comment: @flori is my answer acceptable or do you have questions/concerns?

Answer (score 0):

```
$n = 1
for( $i=$n;$i=$n;)
    {
        unset($arOne[$i]); 
        unset($arSnd[$i]);
        unset($arThd[$i]);
        break;
    }
```

I think this will also perfectly.